# How can I convert txt files with this type of data to json?

Tags: javascript, json, csv

So I'm just trying to use some data that I got in JavaScript but its not in a suitable format. It's .txt file and it's not really formatted well.

I've tried to find out what format the data in the .txt file was but I couldn't.

Here's an example of what the .txt file contains:

```
age, name, height_cm
20, John, 176
35, Robert, 185
28, Julia, 162
```

Of course the .txt file is different and contains hundreds of lines.

So I need some guidance in finding a way to convert this data to json if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a dedicated CSV parser that is specifically designed for this type of problem, it will handle quoted fields and all other kind of gotchas for you.

I would definitely avoid rolling your own.. these libraries are [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) compliant.

[jquery-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-csv) is one, [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/) is another that are worth trying.

With jquery-csv it's pretty simple to parse text to objects:

```js
const csv = 
`age,name,height_cm
20,John,176
35,Robert,185
28,Julia,162`;

const options = { separator: "," };

console.log("CSV input:", `\n${csv}\n\n`);
console.log("Parsed output:", $.csv.toObjects(csv, options));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/1.0.5/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works quite well, I'm just unsure how I would go through the whole text file and add a newline character at each new line?

Comment: Oh you shouldn't have to, the csv parser should deal with all of that. I'm presuming your file has either Unix style ("\n", LF) or Windows ("\r\n", CRLF) line termination characters in it?